# Understanding Equation of Serpentine Locomotion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, torque, angular-velocity

I'm trying to understand and equation for serpentine locomotion. However, I'm having a little trouble understanding it.

$$ \Phi(t) = \alpha \sin(\omega t + (i-1)\beta) + \gamma $$

I know like $t$ is time and I'm guessing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ refer to angles but I'm having trouble understanding the rest.

Source: https://projects.ics.forth.gr/bioloch/internal/papers/snake_robot.pdf (Page 10-11) Serpentine Locomotion

I'm trying to understand how I would use the equation.

Comment: Welcome to this community. Can you give more background to your question, for example where the equation comes from and what's your goal (if any) after understanding it?

Comment: Does *serpentine locomotion* mean *wave motion*, or does it literally mean the way snakes move? Can you provide a reference to where you got this equation from? Without a reference it's hard for us to say what the different variables mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community. You may want to look at the below link that breaks down equations of the form:

$$y(x)=A \sin(Bx+C)+D$$

In your case, $y(x)=\Phi(t)$; $x=t$; $A=\alpha$; $B=\omega$; $C=(i−1)\beta$ and $D=\gamma$. This should help you understand what you are looking at.

http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa09/Gonterman/Gonterman1/Gonterman1.html